# I want to create a "snapping" horizontal scoll view in android which fixes itself at a particular view at a time

Tags: android

What we call "snapping" horizontal scroll view.
For example the default android calculator app whose a set of keys are fixed on screen unless user swipes it away to get another set. How do I achieve this kind of scrolling? I used simple HorizontalScrollView widget for the purpose, but it's not what I want.![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a ViewPager layout - the same layout you would use to achieve a tabbed user interface.

The documentation for ViewPager is available here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html